# Limiting a VBA time stamp in excel to only a few rows

Tags: vba, excel, time

I am trying to create a table that tracks downtime for a production machine. the operator will be using a table with the columns down time start and down time stop. each time something happens that they have to leave the station I want them just to have to click the empty cell under downtime stat title and the time will appear/ log itself in the cell then the same for downtime stop.

I have the following code that works to the point that if I click anywhere in columns G and H the current time will show up:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

 'Check to see if the click/selected cell is in columns A or B
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G:H")) Is Nothing Then

     'Make sure just one cell is selected:
     If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

         'Update the value
         Target.Value = Now()
     End If
 End If
End Sub
```

how do I make it so the time will only show up if click in a range of rows? right now if i click on the column title it is changed to the current time, which i dont want.

Thank you for the help

Comment: How about something like this: `If Target.Row <= 2 Then Exit Sub` (where you will have to adjust to the header row).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Check to see if the click/selected cell is in columns A or B
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G:H")) Is Nothing Then

        'Make sure just one cell is selected:
        If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Row > 1 and Target.Row <= SomeNumber Then

            'Update the value
            Target.Value = Now()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want

```
If Target.Row > some number and Target.Row < some other number and (Target.Column = 7 or Target.Column = 8) and Target.Cells.Count = 1 then
    Target.Value = Now()
End If
```